# iOS Application crashes on real device. Error: dyld`__abort_with_payload

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, dart, signing

I am facing a problem for 3 days where I can't open my developed apps on my iPhone Xr.
I am using Flutter for the base and XCode for signing the Application. Whenever the app gets installed to my device I get this error message as I try to open the app:

```
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
0x1050772a4 <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209
0x1050772a8 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
-> 0x1050772ac <+8>:  b.lo   0x1050772c8               ; <+36> . //THE ERROR OCCURS HERE
0x1050772b0 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
0x1050772b4 <+16>: mov    x29, sp
0x1050772b8 <+20>: bl     0x1050757d8               ; cerror_nocancel
0x1050772bc <+24>: mov    sp, x29
0x1050772c0 <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
0x1050772c4 <+32>: ret    
0x1050772c8 <+36>: ret
```

and

```
dyld`_dyld_start:
0x105029000 <+0>:   mov    x28, sp
0x105029004 <+4>:   and    sp, x28, #0xfffffffffffffff0
0x105029008 <+8>:   mov    x0, #0x0
0x10502900c <+12>:  mov    x1, #0x0
0x105029010 <+16>:  stp    x1, x0, [sp, #-0x10]!
0x105029014 <+20>:  mov    x29, sp
0x105029018 <+24>:  sub    sp, sp, #0x10             ; =0x10 
0x10502901c <+28>:  ldr    x0, [x28]
0x105029020 <+32>:  ldr    x1, [x28, #0x8]
0x105029024 <+36>:  add    x2, x28, #0x10            ; =0x10 
0x105029028 <+40>:  adrp   x3, -1
0x10502902c <+44>:  add    x3, x3, #0x0              ; =0x0 
0x105029030 <+48>:  mov    x4, sp
0x105029034 <+52>:  bl     0x10502907c               ; 
dyldbootstrap::start(dyld3::MachOLoaded const*, int, char const**, dyld3::MachOLoaded const*, unsigned long*)
->  0x105029038 <+56>:  mov    x16, x0               // HERE THE ERROR OCCURS AS WELL
0x10502903c <+60>:  ldr    x1, [sp]
0x105029040 <+64>:  cmp    x1, #0x0                  ; =0x0 
0x105029044 <+68>:  b.ne   0x105029050               ; <+80>
0x105029048 <+72>:  add    sp, x28, #0x8             ; =0x8 
0x10502904c <+76>:  braaz  x16
0x105029050 <+80>:  mov    x30, x1
0x105029054 <+84>:  ldr    x0, [x28, #0x8]
0x105029058 <+88>:  add    x1, x28, #0x10            ; =0x10 
0x10502905c <+92>:  add    x2, x1, x0, lsl #3
0x105029060 <+96>:  add    x2, x2, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x105029064 <+100>: mov    x3, x2
0x105029068 <+104>: ldr    x4, [x3]
0x10502906c <+108>: add    x3, x3, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x105029070 <+112>: cmp    x4, #0x0                  ; =0x0 
0x105029074 <+116>: b.ne   0x105029068               ; <+104>
0x105029078 <+120>: braaz  x16
```

In the logs:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FMDB.framework/FMDB
Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/860A658F-17FA-4D3B-B41E-896BA0444E5F/Runner.app/Runner
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/860A658F-17FA-4D3B-B41E-896BA0444E5F/Runner.app/Frameworks/FMDB.framework/FMDB: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/860A658F-17FA-4D3B-B41E-896BA0444E5F/Runner.app/Frameworks/FMDB.framework/FMDB'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/860A658F-17FA-4D3B-B41E-896BA0444E5F/Runner.app/Frameworks/FMDB.framework/FMDB: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/860A658F-17FA-4D3B-B41E-896BA0444E5F/Runner.app/Frameworks/FMDB.framework/FMDB'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/860A658F-17FA-4D3B-B41E-896BA0444E5F/Runner.app/Frameworks/FMDB.framework/FMDB: stat() failed with errno=1
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/860A658F-17FA-4D3B-B41E-896BA0444E5F/Runner.app/Frameworks/FMDB.framework/FMDB: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/860A658F-17FA-4D3B-B41E-896BA0444E5F/Runner.app/Frameworks/FMDB.framework/FMDB'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/860A658F-17FA-4D3B-B41E-896BA0444E5F/Runner.app/Frameworks/FMDB.framework/FMDB: stat() failed with errno=1
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/860A658F-17FA-4D3B-B41E-896BA0444E5F/Runner.app/Frameworks/FMDB.framework/FMDB: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/860A658F-17FA-4D3B-B41E-896BA0444E5F/Runner.app/Frameworks/FMDB.framework/FMDB'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/860A658F-17FA-4D3B-B41E-896BA0444E5F/Runner.app/Frameworks/FMDB.framework/FMDB: stat() failed with errno=1
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/860A658F-17FA-4D3B-B41E-896BA0444E5F/Runner.app/Frameworks/FMDB.framework/FMDB: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/860A658F-17FA-4D3B-B41E-896BA0444E5F/Runner.app/Frameworks/FMDB.framework/FMDB'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/860A658F-17FA-4D3B-B41E-896BA0444E5F/Runner.app/Frameworks/FMDB.framework/FMDB: stat() failed with errno=1
(lldb)
```

I don't know why this error message came. It came suddenly, I do not have changed any major things in my project. Even with complete new projects this error occurs. 
On simulator it is working fine and on Android as well. 
(This seems to be a problem with my device?)

I would appreciate your help. Thanks for reading my problem.

For further contact:
Discord: emrepro#7866

Edit (27.4.2020), After several reinstallations and a reset of my mac it suddenly started working again.
I think that it went back because the iOS version was compatible again. I was using a beta version of iOS. So just update to the newest stable beta or normal version and freshly reinstall xcode and you‘ll be fine.

Comment: Have you tried clean and rebuild

Comment: @flutter yes I did it several times changed nothing :( I even did clean build folders in xcode

Comment: same problem here, just fresh install flutter, run smoothly on simulator but not on real device (iPhone 6s)

Comment: @oentoro I haven't got the problem solved up to this day.. very sad.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this problem yet?

Comment: Apparently no. I am still waiting. @maddyeng

Answer (score 0):

Device issue comes when flutter install is not properly.
Please see below terminal commands :

1. flutter doctor
2. sudo gem install cocoapods
3. pod setup
4. flutter clean

Run these commands. Refer to this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos) for more details

Comment: I ran everything, here you can see some logs: https://pastebin.com/cpWveZp5

Comment: Oh my bad, I have seen your logs. Let me know one thing have you tried deleting all Certificate and provisioning profile and download again then try to run may be this will solve the issue. I think think this is signing issue. Thanks

Comment: I deleted all my certificates from keychain. But how can I delete my provisioning profiles?

Comment: see apple developer for pp.

Comment: i deletes all my pps but the error is still occuring.

Comment: same I deleted pp, and removed certs still no resolution.